# When to specify 'public' explicitly in swift even if its not a framework?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

I currently declare my properties in my main app like this:

```
public var thingA: String?
private var thingB: String?
private var thingC: String?
```

Should I omit the 'public' declaration within the main module as no other modules will need to use the thingA. such that it looks more like:

```
var thingA: String?
private var thingB: String?
private var thingC: String?
```

If we omit the 'public' here it simply means that if it was in a framework it could no longer be accessed from elsewhere, but in the main app/module, that simply isnt a concern so there's not only no point in using public but its arguably bad practice to be giving greater access than is required... (And maybe compiler related inefficiencies??)

Whats the agreed standard as I cant seem to find anything addressing this in documentation or stackoverflow?

Comment: I don’t believe there is something like an agreed standard here. Personally I never use the public keyword in app code since I see no point in doing so.

Comment: public should be most observed properties. At least I do public on properties that I have property observer on and needs exposure to other views or controllers for setup; For example `shouldFitToBounds` or `isAnimated` so that the closure(s) can run on them. Additionally on properties that are get only or related to config. Otherwise private or fileprivate all. I think the best design principle here is to explicitly private most of the properties and explicitly figure out your public interface. Makes your logic and the code more robust no lazy interfacing from outside if that was not intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access Controls are defined [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html). If no specific access control is defined it means it will have `internal` access control that allows access of that entity within the same module. Default access control is also `internal` and as mentioned in the link above, if you are working on a single target app, you can omit defining a specific access control(i.e, no need for `public` access control).

However, i believe you should always start with `private` access control and change it later as per the requirement.

Comment: I agree with the idea of defining private first, so in practice you would simply omit the access control in any circumstance where it should be considered 'internal'? I guess the confusion is stemmed from a lot of very senior engineers in our team over the course of many years using public where it seems they really had the intent to mean 'internal'... typically from objective-c backgrounds.

Comment: In `Swift`, within the app with single target, no reason to use `public` or `open`(may be with some exceptions). You can  check this **Access Levels for Single-Target Apps** in the above link.